# Listing and loading class within jar

Tags: java, jar, classloader

In a project i need to load different `jar` files under a specific directory. Then i will search `.class` files which implements a specific `interface`. and when i found searched one, i need to load it with `Class.forName()`. Is there an easy way to do all this? Can you propose some sample code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also like the approach of Mark if your in a plain Java Application and want to define the Interface <-> Implementation(s) mapping upfront.

Another way of doing what you want I think is tinker with classpath scanning where you consider the currently running classpath and use it to find components by Annotation or Interface.

Popular example for this is for example [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning).

To use that outside of Spring you could try using some library like [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) or [Class-Search](http://code.google.com/p/class-search/) which offer an API to search inside the classpath.

Since I recently tinkered with Vaadin/GWT and their approach to find something inside the current classpath, [this class](http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/versions/6.8/src/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/widgetsetutils/ClassPathExplorer.java) from their tools could be interesting for you as well if you want to implement something like that manually.

But like Martijn already mentioned these solutions would need to add the JAR to your classpath so the class gets loaded and then interpret the found components.

If that's critical and you can't load the class upfront and interpret it later, you could try to build something above a library like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org) which can perhaps offer interpretation of a `.class`-file without loading the class.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). This does require the implementer of these classes to supply a descriptive file in `/META-INF/services/<fqn-of-interface>` listing all implementation classes provided by the jar for that interface.

Comment: it seems to remedy to my problem. i will google some sample code for it. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't check if the class implements a specific interface without loading it first. So, I think you have to load every class file or try to solve your problem/achieve your target a different way.

You could try to read the .class file binary and find out in the byte code which interface it implements, but don't ask me how to do this. :)

Comment: yes you are right. my actual problem is finding the full class name (with package) since Class.forName() is expecting full name. I dont know class names in jar beforehand.